# How to send a search to backend for server processing then send processed data back to frontend?

Tags: http, post, get, web-deployment

I have a React JS frontend and a python backend. It is a web scraping application where you enter a search on the frontend and it sends the search to the backend then the backend webscrapes the necessary data and sends it back to the frontend. Currently, I am using a POST request to send the search then immediately doing a GET request to receive the scraped data. Can you accomplish this with just a GET request or another way?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and I have used Django REST for back-end and React.js for front-end.

Front-end:

1. Design a UI, where the user interacts and provides necessary data.
2. For the user input, you can use Formik and Yup.
3. Use Axios to send a POST request to the backend, with required parameters.

Back-end:

1. Design an API endpoint that accepts POST request and have required logic over here and you can store data in models for further usage.
2. Once data is validated by serializers, you can save data in Django models and return the data to the user. Hence you will get scraped data in the single POST request.

Django REST would be my first option for the back-end.